# Convert date into format %d%m%y Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, python-3.9

I have a problem in Python 3.9 64x bit.
In a program I am writing, I need to be able to convert any inputted date into the format %d%m%y.
For example, if the user entered 12 December 2021, the program will convert it to 121221, and if the user enters 2021 12 December, it will still convert it to 121221.

Comment: If ambiguity is not expected, split the string and guess each substring. A day has len() < 3, a month is in the set of months the least is a year. If ambiguity is possible the task is impossible.

Comment: It seems ironic that you convert the dates to a totally ambiguous format. If the user imputted "121221", how do you decide what year/century was intended?

Comment: I am trying to scrape skyscanner, and I need the date to be in this format to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from_date="12 December 2021"
>>> import time                
>>> conv=time.strptime(from_date,"%d %B %Y")
>>> time.strftime("%d/%m/%y",conv)
'121221'

>>> from_date="2021 12 December"
>>> import time                
>>> conv=time.strptime(from_date,"%Y %d %B")
>>> time.strftime("%d%m%y",conv)
'121221'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` `to_datetime` and then `strftime`.

```
from pandas import to_datetime
to_datetime('12 December 2021').strftime('%d%m%y') ## returns 121221
to_datetime('2021 12 December').strftime('%d%m%y') ## returns 121221
```

`pandas` tries to infer the format when parsing the string.

Note, without specifying the datetime format for the string entered by the user there is of course ambiguity. E.g. what is meant by a the string `'11/12/2021'`. It could be `'11 December 2021'` or `'12 November 2021'`.
this of course is error prone if the user enters